# Primefaces Dialog is not resetting selected values on second time view

Tags: primefaces, dialog

I am having a `dataTable` in my xhtml that will show the records and at the last column in the `dataTable`, I am having a `commandButton` that will display a dialog that has a selectOneMenu which the user can select the date and based on the date selection, the values will be printed in `outputText` fields. The code is:

```
<h:form id="f1">
    <p:dataTable id="Requests">
        <p:commandButton id="View" update=":BankSearchForm:tab1:#{c.dialogueName}"
                oncomplete="PF('#{c.certificateDialogue}').show()" title="View">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{c}" target="#{bcd.selectedRequest}"/>
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:dataTable>

    <p:dialog header="SSA" widgetVar="SSDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade"
            hideEffect="fade" resizable="false" width="1200px">
        <p:outputPanel id="BSSEN" style="text-align:center;" autoUpdate="true">
            <p:selectOneMenu id="SelectMonth" value="#{bcd.selectedMonth}">
                <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{bcd.BSSCert}"/>
                <f:selectItems label="#{bcd.coffee2Value}" value="#{bcd.coffee2Value}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

For the first time when I click on the `commandButton`, the dialog will be shown and I can select any value from the `selectOneMenu`and when the I close the `dialog` and click again on the `commandButton`, the earlier selected values will be shown again where they should be reset to default and the outputLabels should be blank. So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your dialog panel when showing the dialog.

```
<p:commandButton id="View" update="BSSEN :BankSearchForm:tab1:#{c.dialogueName}"
```

Comment: This should not have been needed since the outputPanel has `autoUpdate="true"` But this just might not have worked due to the commandButton not having any (action)Listener